# Ember.js route is not performing a new request when params change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, ember.js, ember-router, nested-resources

I'm working in my first web app with Ember.js backed with a Rails for API. 
I have the following nested resources:

```
this.resource('selection_processes', function() {
  this.resource('selection_process', { path: '/:selection_process_id' }, function() {
    this.resource('candidate', { path: '/candidates/:candidate_id' });
  });
})
```

So, when I access `selection_processes/1` it's getting all of its candidates. Thats ok, but the problem is when I click on another selection process link Ember does not perform a new request, rendering no data in my templates. Btw, the API is returning the correct objects.

The only way I got this working was including all objects in my serializers, making Ember getting all the data of the whole nested resources in a single request. But this seems to be a lazy practice and "heavy".

By the way, here are my routes:

```
Safira.SelectionProcessesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.find('selection_process');
  }
});


Safira.SelectionProcessRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return this.store.find('selection_process', params.selection_process_id);
  }
});


Safira.CandidateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return this.store.find('candidate', params.candidate_id);
  }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Here are my models

```
Safira.SelectionProcess = DS.Model.extend({
  beginDate         : DS.attr('date'),
  endDate           : DS.attr('date'),
  title              : DS.attr('string'),
  description       : DS.attr('string'),
  steps             : DS.hasMany('Safira.Step', {async: true})
});

Safira.Step = DS.Model.extend({
  realization: DS.attr('date'),
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  candidates: DS.hasMany('Safira.Candidate', {async: true}),
  selection_process : DS.belongsTo('Safira.SelectionProcess')
});

Safira.Candidate = DS.Model.extend({
  name               : DS.attr('string'),
  email              : DS.attr('string'),
  confirmation_token : DS.attr('string'),
  step               : DS.belongsTo('Safira.Step')
});
```

Comment: Can you show your models?

Comment: Sure, I just updated.

Comment: Can you confirm that your server is returning the candidate ids? When rendering, are you doing something like `{{#each steps}}` then `{{#each candidates}}`? Is it rendering the `steps`?

Comment: Yes, it's returning the candidates and steps ids. It's rendering steps too. When I enter a url like ``selection_processes/2`` directly it works fine, rendering all data. But if I navigate through a link-to to display another selection process (selection_processes/3, for example), it returns nothing, unless I enter url directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to pass same data in both cases.(when you get a collection or individual items).
I think you are returning partial data in case of collection.
When you go through a link it assumes it already has data for that model so it won't send a new request. IMO you should be able to access partial data of that model received in collection.

if the model is big, split it into multiple models. it require server side change also.